# Concrete5 Content Block content into pagelist

Tags: php, concrete5

i'm building this website where i have event list on frontpage. I do this by using
pagelist block. Now my customer also want to show date of current event. I have created my own
event page template where i have this "date" block (ordinary content block) where user just types date he/she wants. Now i want this "date" to be part of pagelist..like so

> 12.10.2014 - Lorem ipsum

How do i do this ? I'm not php coder..

At first i tried Simple Event add-on but it did not work out because language of Concrete5 (finnish)..

// Mika

Comment: This is definitely possible to do, but it requires PHP coding within the template file or creating a custom block.  Either way, you will be in PHP, unless you can find an event Add-On that will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Pages and their attributes are easy to search and list in many different formats. Blocks are not.

If the date associated with each page was a page attribute, then it would be easy to list it with the page using many of the various page list addons or templates (including my own Uber List). So start by looking for a page list addon/template that includes dates or attributes, then work back from that to decide how you need to attach the date attribute to each event page.

Within the event pages, you can then either edit the date using the usual page attribute dialog and then revise your date block to just show that attribute, or revise your date block to save its data in that attribute, so editing the block edits the date (or use my Front End Attribute Editor block).

You don't really need your date block as there are already addons that can display page attributes (including my own Magic Data addon).

While I have given examples using my own addons, there are plenty of other page listing and attribute displaying blocks available. The thing they all have in common is making the date an attribute of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the date a page attribute instead of a block, then it is very easy to retrieve it in the PageList (using `$date = $page->getAttribute('your_date_attribute_handle')` within the foreach loop of the page list template).